# Everytime I click on my website, it redirects to home.html then back to desired url I have clicked on

Tags: javascript, html

As the title suggests. I am having troubles with my website. When ever I click on a link, I would get my home.html showing up. Then it will go to the desired link. It is only for a few seconds. However it gets really annoying when I am trying to back up on my searches that I have done. My code for index.html is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>M3TA4.NET</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="M3TA4.NET"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="M3TA4.NET, m3ta4, m3ta4dotnet, m3ta4.com, m3ta4dotcom, sir0m3ta4, 3d objects, homepage, help, wallpapers, backgrounds, 3d, blender models, blender3d models, models, free software, software,"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="micon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="icon" href="micon.ico" type="image/ico" />

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
    html, body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background:#000;
    }
    #hdr {
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        background:#fff;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #hdr_btns {
        width:875px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #hdr_btns img {
        height:40px;
    }
    #middle {
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        background:#fff;
        top:60px;
        left:0;
        bottom:60px;
        height:auto;
        right:0;
        width:100%;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    #middle iframe {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:relative;
            background:#fff;
            border:0;
        }
    #ftr {
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;
        background:#fff;
        position:absolute;
        top:auto;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        height:60px;
        width:100%;
    }
    #ftr_btns {
        width:640px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .btns {
            display:block;
            float:left;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-top:0px;
            background:#fff;
        }
        input {
            border:0px solid #fff;
        }
        #logo {
            position:absolute;
            display:block;
            right:10px;
            bottom:26px;
            left:auto;
            top:auto;
            width:200px;
            height:auto;            
        }
        #logo img {
            width:200px;
        }

        @media (min-width: 1300px) {

            #hdr_btns {
                width:1300px;
            }

            #hdr_btns img {
                height:60px;
            }

        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clk(url){

            document.getElementById('content').src=url;

        };
        function loadsource(){
            var defaultPage = "home.html";
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var pos = query.indexOf('=');
            if (pos > 0){
                var frameSource = query.substring(pos+1);
                //window.frames["content"].location = frameSource;
                document.getElementById('content').src= frameSource;

            }else{
                //window.frames["content"].location = defaultPage;
                document.getElementById('content').src= defaultPage;
            }
        };
    </script>


</head>
<body onload="loadsource()">
    <div id="hdr">
        <div id="hdr_btns">
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://m3ta4.net/index.html?page=3dobjects.html"><img src="linkz/3dobjectzon.png" onmouseover="this.src='linkz/3dobjectzoff.png'" onmouseout="this.src='linkz/3dobjectzon.png'" onclick="this.src='linkz/3dobjectzclick.png'" border="0" alt="3d objects page"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://m3ta4.net/index.html?page=software.html"><img src="linkz/freesoftwareon.png" onmouseover="this.src='linkz/freesoftwareoff.png'" onmouseout="this.src='linkz/freesoftwareon.png'" onclick="this.src='linkz/freesoftwareclick.png'" border="0" alt="free software page"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://m3ta4.net/index.html?page=helpdesk.html"><img src="linkz/helpdeskon.png" onmouseover="this.src='linkz/helpdeskoff.png'" onmouseout="this.src='linkz/helpdeskon.png'" onclick="this.src='linkz/helpdeskclick.png'" border="0" alt="free software page"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://m3ta4.net/index.html?page=reviews/reviews.html"><img src="linkz/reviewzon.png" onmouseover="this.src='linkz/reviewzoff.png'" onmouseout="this.src='linkz/reviewzon.png'" onclick="this.src='linkz/reviewzclick.png'" border="0" alt="free software page"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://m3ta4.net/index.html?page=wallpapers.html"><img src="linkz/freewallpaperon.png" onmouseover="this.src='linkz/freewallpaperoff.png'" onmouseout="this.src='linkz/freewallpaperon.png'" onclick="this.src='linkz/freewallpaperclick.png'" border="0" alt="free software page"/></a></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="middle" >
        <iframe id="content" name="content" src="home.html" border="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="ftr" >

        <div id="ftr_btns">
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/M3TA4NET/249868325065235" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/facebook.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/facebook.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/facebook.png'" height="60px"border="0" alt="Facebook.com link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/metaphor26" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/youtube.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/youtube.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/youtube.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="Youtube.com link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.gmail.com/" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/gmail.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/gmail.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/gmail.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="Gmail.com link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.mail.com" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/mail.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/mail.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/mail.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="Mail.com link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.blender.org/" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/blender.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://m3ta4.net/linkz/blender.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/blender.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="blender.org link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.ubuntu.com/" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/ubuntu.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/ubuntu.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/ubuntu.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="ubuntu.com link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.gumtree.com.au" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/gumtree.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://m3ta4.net/linkz/gumtree.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/gumtree.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="Gumtree.com.au link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.ebay.com.au" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/ebay.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/ebay.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/ebay.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="Ebay.com link"/></a></div>
            <div class="btns"><a href="http://www.rewardscentral.com.au/Join/Default.aspx?refer=dru_b" target="blank"><img src="http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/rewardscentral.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/rewardscentral.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.m3ta4.net/linkz/rewardscentral.png'" height="60px" border="0" alt="Rewardscentral link"/></a></div>


        </div>
    </div>

    <a id="logo" href="home.html" target="content"><img src="m3ta4-logo.png" alt="logo" border="0"/></a>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have also uploaded a youtube video to show what is happening.
[video of the issue](http://youtu.be/NHdSLMYqB4g)(Note youtube video has been deleted.)

If you need any more information I am happy to give it to you. 
Also like to note that I pretty new to coding web pages.

Comment: spam? (i'm not sure)

Comment: yeah. i think its spam. to make many click on his web

Comment: I'm not so sure. You can see from the code posted there is the problem he has described.

Comment: not spam just trying to fix the problem am i missing something? i will delete this post after my issue is resolved. Can you see what I am talking about when it is redirecting to my home.html and then the desired link?

Comment: Don't think i can delete a question I have asked sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `src` attribute from your `iframe` element:

```
<iframe id="content" name="content" border="0"></iframe>
```

Currently, when you click a link, it reloads the page. Your `loadSource` function isn't firing until the page has been loaded. This means the page renders first, with the `iframe` having loaded `home.html` into the `iframe`. Then `loadSource` is firing, which then changes the content of the `iframe` dependent on the link clicked.

Comment: Omg thankyou so much fixed the problem right away. Dont know how I missed that. well Ill blame it on my newbness!